# apache/php multiple users mapped to multiple versions of app

Tags: php, mysql, apache, .htaccess

*(updated file structure)*

I've got this situation:

- a general database with several users (unique_name, database_name, user, password, version)
- a release folder with different versions of the app. (releases/version/...)
- each user has his own database, from which the info is found in the general database.

if a user navigates to "http://www.app.com/unique_name/", I want the server to:

- load the correct user info from the general database
- load the correct version of the app (and the correct assets)
- use the correct user database in the app.

The users can only see "http://www.app.com/unique_name/" in it's browser, and there will be API calls to "http://www.app.com/unique_name/api/...".

file structure:

```
/
  data/
    unique_name/   (files for unique_name)
    unique_name2/  (files for unique_name2)
    ...
  releases/
    v1.5/
      index.php
      api/
    v2.0/
      index.php
      api/
```

What would be a correct way to approach this using apache and php?

Answer (score 0):

Your question need more details from your side but what i could understand, In this case you have to be very decisive on project structure,

Make url looks like -> www.app.com/index.php?/unique_name

1. Create a bootstrap file which handle all request(landing) and pass unique_name as a parameter, you can use .htaccess file for this
2. Parse the url and get the first segment, Gets the Database and version details from general database based on argument and cache or store it in session(user data + version folder mapping) it.
3. Loads the correct version of file-system using php(may be need to write a router class)

www.app.com/api/index.php?/unique_name

---

```
src\
    api\
        index.php
    releases\
         xxx.xxx\
         xxx.xxx\

    index.php
```

As far as api code, i would advise to place all api related code at top level.
You need to write some router(mapper) which will make the absolute path of assets or files, can be used for loading.

Comment: the file structure is a little different, I've updated my question. If I create a landing page, which gets the correct info from the general database, how can I make a "symbolic" link to the correct version folder?

Comment: Just include the file into main /index.php based on user associated release dir, like require_once('./release/v1.5/api/index.php');